# Can't obtain information with ffmpeg from Smooth Streaming Manifest file

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, manifest, smooth-streaming

I'm trying to get details for a stream of protocol Microsoft Smooth Streaming, with ffmpeg tools (ffprobe and ffplay) but when I run the next command:

```
ffprobe -i http://b31282.cdn.telefonica.com/31282/Manifest
```

I obtain this:

```
http://b31282.cdn.telefonica.com/31282/Manifest: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I assume that this Manifest file is correct and complies with standards of Smooth Streaming . This is a brief extract of Manifest file:

```
<SmoothStreamingMedia MajorVersion="2" MinorVersion="0" Duration="0" TimeScale="10000000" IsLive="TRUE" LookAheadFragmentCount="2" DVRWindowLength="6000000000" CanSeek="TRUE" CanPause="TRUE">
  <Protection>
    <ProtectionHeader SystemID="9a04f079-9840-4286-ab92-e65be0885f95">oioAAAIAAQCUAjwAV...</ProtectionHeader>
  </Protection>
  <StreamIndex Type="audio" Name="audio_esp" Language="esp" Subtype="" Chunks="0" TimeScale="10000000" Url="QualityLevels({bitrate})/Fragments(audio_esp={start time})"></StreamIndex>
  <StreamIndex Type="video" Name="video" Language="" Subtype="" Chunks="0" TimeScale="10000000" Url="QualityLevels({bitrate})/Fragments(video={start time})"></StreamIndex>
</SmoothStreamingMedia>
```

Is a Fedora 21 and ffmpeg version and configuration is:

```
ffmpeg version git-2015-02-27-d490b26
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264
libavutil         54. 19.100         
libavcodec        56. 26.100          
libavformat       56. 23.105           
libavdevice       56.  4.100                   
libavfilter        5. 11.102          
libswscale         3.  1.101        
libswresample      1.  1.100           
libpostproc       53.  3.100
```

**PD**: I prefer use only ffmpeg tool

**PD2**: Same thing with a Microsoft Smooth Streaming Manifest file:

```
ffmpeg -i http://mediadl.microsoft.com/mediadl/iisnet/smoothmedia/Experience/BigBuckBunny_720p.ism/Manifest
Invalid data found when processing input
```

Thanks for all

Comment: I would say the obvious answer is that FFmpeg does not support the operation you are attempting.

Answer (score 0):

smoothstreaming demux is not supported.

Here's the [official doc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html), smoothstreaming doesn't show up in the demux part. And here's the output when you asking what types are supported

```
chang@p300a:~/git-root/FFmpeg$ ffmpeg -formats|grep smooth
ffmpeg version n4.2.3-3-gbf7ed52c25 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --enable-libv4l2 --enable-zlib --enable-vaapi --enable-pthreads --enable-vdpau --enable-xlib --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-gnutls --enable-openssl --enable-nonfree --disable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdrm
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  E smoothstreaming Smooth Streaming Muxer
```